# Can I somehow use a package with a later version of base than what the package specifies?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm quite new to the Haskell stack, so I might be misunderstanding how things are intended to work here, but I have a problem that I've seen a few times and am wondering if I'm going about the wrong way.

In short, I sometimes want to use a package with a version spec that is capped at a lower version of `base` than what my Stack resolver includes.

For example, I can't use the `lts-12.14`  resolver with `PSQueue-1.1`, because  the former includes `base-4.11.1` and the latter requires `base >=4 && <4.11`.

The two ways I have found to resolve that has been to either

- add a specific version of `base` to my `extra-deps`, making sure that the pinned version is within the range my package allows; or
- choose a different resolver (using e.g. https://www.stackage.org/diff/ to figure out which one is the latest resolver with an early enough version of `base`)

Both of these feel suboptimal, especially since I might want to use packages which have non-overlapping ranges (e.g. one `>=3 && <4.11` and one `>=4.11`). I realize that using such a combination toghether *might* fail, especially if they are locked on different major-versions of `base` (assuming `base` uses semver), but so far I'm only writing pretty small programs, so if they seem to work I'm quite happy even if there are other, non-exercised code paths that will fail on the specific combination of packages and versions. In other words: I know the risk - but I can't chance it, because I don't know how to.

Is there a way to force Stack to allow a newer version of `base` than the one specified in the requirements of a dependency?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for `allow-newer` - https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#allow-newer

> Ignore version bounds in .cabal files. Default is false.

Comment: Thanks! That solves my immediate problem, but it seems it might get me into new ones. Mainly: with this flag enabled, how do I _know_ that a newer version has been selected? Since it might be an error source, it would be nice if I could be explicit about it on specific packages. I take it that is not possible?

Comment: `stack ls dependencies` will tell you what you have got.  If you add a specific version in your cabal file, that should be used.  To be honest you’re asking for headaches.

Comment: "To be honest you're asking for headaches." Quite possibly. But since I'm new to the entire ecosystem, I'm not sure what to expect. For my specific use case, PSQueue just released 1.1.0.1 with support for base-4.11.1, so now I don't need it anymore for this specific project, but that doesn't answer the more general question: if this is a bad solution, what is a good one?

Comment: You can do a number of things: 1) wait for the library to be updated, 2) pin the library to a specific git commit hash, 3) grab the library code as a local dependency (this lets you keep everything stable and just verify the library.). You're generally going to be ok unless their are GHC version requirements.